# How to set up cross domain tracking between a root and subdomain that each have their own GTM and GA containers

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I have ads pointing to our root domain "mydomain.com" and the conversions occur on our subdomain "convert.mydomain.com". I lose any source channel attribution and any conversion/goal tracking once they leave the subdomain.

Here are the facts:

Both domains have their own separate Google Tag Manager (GTM) containers
Both domains have their own Google Analytics (GA) profiles. convert.mydomain.com has both GA profiles tracking in its GTM container.
convert.mydomain.com GTM sends a "cart add" conversion event to the convert.mydomain.com GA, but not the mydomain.com GA.
The GA goal for a "cart checkout" conversion on convert.mydomain.com is a destination goal which tracks on convert.mydomain.com and mydomain.com GA accounts.
Question:

How do I track ad conversions and source channel if the users enter at mydomain.com and convert at convert.mydomain.com?
How does Google Ads know if a person who entered mydomain.com from a Google Ad converted on convert.mydomain.com? (for conversion based bidding reasons)
Thanks in advance for any information on this – I am stumped!

Answer (score 0):

In the View where you send the data of both domains you should see the conversions associated with Google Ads, the important thing is that the `cookieDomain` field is set to `auto` in both GTMs.

Cross-domain tracking with subdomains doesn't matter.